# how to enable only authenticated users to create new users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I guess the title is self explanatory...how do I make only authenticated users to create a user with devise?
when I try to add a new one (when authenticated), devise says that I'm alreade authenticated
any workaround for this?
thanks a lot

edit: as requested, my code

**user form**

```
<% if @user == current_user %>
<i class="icon-info-sign"> </i><i>Após alterar seus dados, você terá de fazer login novamente</i>
<% end %>

<%= form_for(@user, :html => { :class => "well form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div class="alert alert-error">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "erro") %> 
        <% if @user.errors.count == 1 %> impede 
          <% else %>
            impedem
        <% end %>
      a continuação:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>


<label>Nome</label><%= f.text_field :nome %>
<label>E-mail</label><%= f.email_field :email %>

<% if @user == current_user or @user.created_at == nil%>
  <label>Senha</label><%= f.password_field :password %>
<% end %>

<div>
<br />
<button class="btn" type="submit">
    Salvar alterações
</button>

</div>

<% end %>
```

**part of users controller**

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def index
    @users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/new
  # GET /users/new.json
  def new
    @user = User.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /users/1
  # PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**application controller**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        return request.env['omniauth.origin'] || stored_location_for(resource) || painel_path
    end
end
```

**part of routes**

App::Application.routes.draw do

```
  resources :acampantes

  devise_for :users, :skip => [:registrations]

  resources :profiles

  resources :eventos do
    resources :acampantes
  end  

  # aqui tem um has_many, mas não precisa de nested routes
  resources :noticias
  resources :users#, :as => "usuarios"
```

Comment: Have you coded something? Show us what you tried.

Comment: well...I just installed devise on my User model, and generated devise views...haven't changed anything. here is my `User` class: https://gist.github.com/2484961 edit: when i try to add a new user via `/users/sign_up` I get the `You are already logged in` message. same message when `/users/new`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal way to do it would be to override `registrations_controller.rb` (as shown [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/README.md)) and skipping the before_filter check for the `new` and `create` action. I tried to do it myself, but unfortunately, I couldn't get it right.

Another way to do it, which worked for me, would be to create a separate User controller aside from the Registrations controller provided by Devise:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "User saved"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end

# routes.rb
ApplicationName::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :users, :only => [:new, :create]
end
```

Then make a form for the new action:

```
# app/views/users/new.html.erb
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
```

The problem with this approach is that the routes provided by Devise for signing-up still exists. A solution for that would be to prevent Devise from generating routes involving registration:

```
# routes.rb
devise_for :users, :skip => [:registrations]
```

This means that you are going to ignore the Registrations module completely and make your own. I got this idea from the [Bare-bone, stripped-down Devise tutorial](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2011/09/bare-bone-stripped-down-devise/). Take note that you should make the controller actions and views to replace the ones provided by the registrations module of Devise. This includes `new`, `edit`, `create`, `update`, and `destroy`.

Comment: just added `:skip => [:registrations]` worked. I already had the new users form. thanks a lot

Comment: ok, **almost** everything worked...I'm 'kicked out' of my app after I create a new `User`. any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "kicked out"? Are you forced by the app to sign out or something?

Comment: How about editing your question to include the code you've done so far? It's pretty hard to figure out the cause when I can't see anything.

Comment: I'm still not able to figure it out, but if I had to make a guess, it maybe has something to do with omniauth. Try asking other people.

Comment: You can also remove ```:registerable``` from Devise's user model to remove sign_up routes I believe.